# Problem compiling cases environment

Tags: cases

I am trying to compile a simple `cases` example, but I'm having trouble with the tabular separator `&`. Here's my code:

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        x + 1 & \mbox{blabla} \\
        x & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &. x + 1 &

Misplaced alignment tab character &. x &
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to tex exchange! Are you loading the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package? The following MWE works for me `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        x + 1 & \mbox{blabla} \        x & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}`

Comment: I'll also confirm that @cmhughes MWE works for me.  When I remove `\usepackage{amsmath}`, I get the "Misplaced alignment tab character `&`." error that you mention.

Comment: It's a known problem: for historical reasons, LaTeX has an undocumented `\cases` macro inherited from Plain TeX, which has a *very* different syntax than the `cases` environment provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg: Interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I had to load the amsmath package. I had just tried a couple of examples I found on the web which didn't mention the package.

Comment: I think this question and especially the answer are quite helpful to a broader audience. Hence, I am voting for reopen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Short answer

The `cases` environment requires the `amsmath` package:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

### Long answer

For historical reasons, LaTeX defines a `\cases` macro: on page 232 of Lamport's manual one reads

> Most Plain TeX commands can be used in LaTeX, but only with care.

and `\cases` is indeed a Plain TeX command which has quite a different syntax than the `cases` environment. It would be possible to use it without loading `amsmath`, but the features of this package are much better than the Plain TeX commands: more flexible and with a uniform syntax.

By the way, here's how one could input the equation with this method:

```
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 
\cases{
  x + 1 & blabla \cr
  x & otherwise \cr
}
\end{equation}
```

It's evident that the syntax is foreign to LaTeX: the second column is typeset in text mode and not math mode and the lines must be terminated by `\cr`. Most important, the alignment must go between braces: this is the main cause of the error.

*Don't use it* and stick to `\usepackage{amsmath}`.