# How to use a cases environment (in math mode) inside textext/inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I am using the [`textext`](http://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) extension to Inkscape to insert LaTeX into my figure. I am trying to insert a mathematical equation in which I need a `cases` environment, but when I put a:

```
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
        x & x>0, \\
        0 & \textrm{otherwise},
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I get a bunch of errors from `textext`, like `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`. How can I fix this? The example screenshot on the `textext` website has a `cases` environment, so it has to work somehow.

Comment: You've probably hit upon this: [Problem compiling cases environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64408) Edit the preamble file to include `\usepackage{amsmath}`,

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I saw that `textext` has a Preamble file option, but I don't know how to use it. Exactly what does this preamble file contain?

Comment: By default, maybe nothing, I don't really know. You would put stuff that normally goes in the preamble of a LaTeX document (such as `\usepackage{amsmath}`) in it.